# Posting long text from scripted browser (phantomjs) to a php script wont go over 2kb /2400 char

Tags: javascript, php, json, phantomjs

im doing some data scraping using phantomjs (basically its a browser you can code in and run it from command line)

i'm collection information about football matches (teams / countries / leagues , .... ) each as an object , put them all in an array , encode array to jason format and post the result to a php script

result could be a very long text based on amount of games on each day and when that happens i wont get the full text on the php script

in the php script i've stored the posted data in a text file to see whats going on  , each time its about `2.3kb` max and `2397~` characters

while the original posted text which i can see on the terminal is about `40kb` and `40000` chars

so something must be limiting the characters here is my php.ini info which is more than enough  :

```
post_max_size -> 20M
max_input_vars -> 100000
memory_limit -> 256M
```

here the simplified version of my code :

```
var res = page.evaluate(function(sport) {
        var matches = new Array();
        $('div#table-matches').find('.table-main').find('tr').each(function(index, element) {
            var obj = {
                teams :   $(this).find('td').text() ,
                link  :    $(this).find('td').find('a:last').attr('href') ,
            };
         matches.push( obj );
    });
    return matches ;
});

var postBody = 'sport='+sport+'&data='+JSON.stringify(res);

console.log(postBody);
page.open('http://xxxxx/result/save', 'POST', postBody, function(status) {
    phantom.exit();
});
```

here is what i got in the php script :

```
[{"country":"Japan","league":"Emperors Cup","link":"/soccer/japan/emperors-cup/kobe-urawa-65k5LIMh/","match_date":"2015/12/26 04:00","teams":"Kobe - Urawa"},
{"country":"England","league":"Ryman League","link":"/soccer/england/ryman-league/wingate-finchley-metropolitan-police-rwuqgSz9/","match_date":"2015/12/26 12:00","teams":"Wingate
```

the json code has been cut off in the middle , so its not a valid json

is there anything else i should do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's much simpler to look for the answer when HTML that your code operates on is provided in the question (a link to the site is as good).

Luckily you'fe left some clues in a portion of json file, namely the link to one of the pages from the scraped site: /soccer/england/ryman-league/wingate-finchley-metropolitan-police-rwuqgSz9/

If we find it with Google and look at the source it will be clear that data in php script is truncated right at the title of the team «Wingate & Finchley - Metropolitan», that contains an ampersand, which serves as a delimiter for variables and values sent via an URI request and **breaks your `data` variable** into several others.

So, to amend your script you just have to encode the `data` string properly:

`var postBody = 'sport='+sport+'&data='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(res));`

---

**Other way to find the cause** of this issue would be to check $_SERVER and $_POST arrays at the server side, just dumping it to a file and looking if the whole `data` was really present, since you've already done great job checking PHP config that it *should* be present.

---

**A way to go around the issue**, had it not been solved *(if, for example, PhantomJS had a weird bug with POST equests)*, would be to create a temporary file with data and send to php the path to that file (presuming the parsing is done on one and the same server):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = '/tmp/scraped_' + (new Date()).getTime() + ".json";
fs.write(filename, JSON.stringify(res), 'w');
page.open('http://xxxxx/result/save', {"filename" : filename}, function(status) {
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: actually right after posting this question i did the last option suggested by you and dump the data in a text file and red them from text file in php and it works great ... but you might be right about delimiter i never thought of that and automatically assumed its a limitation problem i'll check `url encode `and see what happens but i think i stick with the text file as medium to avoid this kind of problems in the future , thanx

Comment: yes, if you scrape and process data on the same server it's simpler to just save to a file.